# Node.JS WebSocket and Socket

Tags: sockets, node.js, websocket

I want to mix two streams of ordinary socket and WebSocket. All received socket messages should be broadcasted over websocket to all connected users.

I have this part of code:

```
var net = require('net');
var io = require('socket.io').listen(13673, 'localhost');

net.createServer(function (stream) {
  stream.setEncoding('utf8');
  stream.on('data', function (data) {
    // HERE SHOULD BE WS BROADCAST
    console.log(data);
  });
}).listen(24768);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('message', function (text) {
    var message = {
      'type': 'message',
      'received': new Date(),
      'text': text
    };

    socket.broadcast.json.send([message]);
    socket.json.send([message]);
  });
});
```

So, as apart it works just fine, but I want listen to normal socket all the time and process received messages to WebSocket. Put one into other doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try keeping an array of connected WebSocket clients, and when you receive a TCP socket message, loop through the array and broadcast to each client:

```
var net = require('net');
var io = require('socket.io').listen(13673, 'localhost');

var clients = [];

net.createServer(function (stream) {
    stream.setEncoding('utf8');
    stream.on('data', function (data) {
        // HERE SHOULD BE WS BROADCAST
        for(var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++)
            clients[i].json.send(/*your message*/);
        console.log(data);
    });
}).listen(24768);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    clients.push(socket);
});
```

Comment: Is this the only solution to hold all the sockets as array and then loop thru them? What about performance?

Comment: Don't worry about performance until it's a problem. Golden rule of programming.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use **io.sockets.emit** function for broadcasting to sockets connected through socket.io

```
var express = require('express')
        , app = express()
        , server = require('http').createServer(app)
        , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("NEW SOCKET");
});

function sendToBrowser(message){
    io.sockets.emit('news', {data: message});
}
```